# OpenCV Python - findHomography with RANSAC

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to run [findHomography()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#Mat%20findHomography(InputArray%20srcPoints,%20InputArray%20dstPoints,%20int%20method,%20double%20ransacReprojThreshold,%20OutputArray%20mask,%20const%20int%20maxIters%20,%20const%20double%20confidence)) using RANSAC, but I'm receiving a TypeError. My code works when I don't specify method at all, but even `method=0` causes a TypeError.

**Code**

```
    T, mask = cv2.findHomography(points_subset[i], points_subset[i+1], False, method=cv2.RANSAC)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stab.py", line 368, in <module>
    stabilize_video(path, video_name)
  File "stab.py", line 331, in stabilize_video
    transforms, points, frame = calc_transformations(cap)
  File "stab.py", line 113, in calc_transformations
    T, mask = cv2.findHomography(points_subset[i], points_subset[i+1], False, method=cv2.RANSAC)
TypeError: Argument given by name ('method') and position (3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is occurring because you are attempting to specify the `method` parameter twice; once as a positional argument, and again as a keyword argument. The `False` argument can be removed to correct your error. If you are trying to use RANSAC to find the homography, the correct call looks like this:

```
T, mask = cv2.findHomography(points_subset[i], points_subset[i+1], method=cv2.RANSAC)
```

Comment: thank you. also, do you know how I might use RANSAC with estimateRigidTransform()? It doesn't look like it's implemented in OpenCV, so I guess I'll have to do it myself? http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform

Comment: @Apollo It appears `estimateRigidTransform` uses RANSAC internally. See [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp). Also, if this answer was correct, would you accept it?

Comment: that was a very helpful find :)